# Disable file updating in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

is it possible to disable file updating in AWS S3 ?

I would like S3 to send an error if a file with the same path / name is uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

It is **not possible** to generate a warning if an object is placed into Amazon S3 with an existing `Key` (filename).

If this is important, then your application should use `HeadObject()` to check whether the object exists.

If Versioning is activated on the bucket, then an upload to the same Key as an existing object will create a new version of the object. The previous version version will also be retained.

See: [Using versioning - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html)